# TYPO3 record issues

Tags: typo3, backend, records

I am facing a TYPO3 Backend Error. I added some records to a page and they are showing up on the View Page. Then I delete this records and they still show up.

The records are not visible or existing. I cleared the FE cache, the page cache, all the caches, the records still showing up.

Did I miss anything?

Best
Chris

Comment: what kind of records?

Answer (score 1):

have a look in your database (with phpmyadmin or similar). TYPO3 does not realy delete records but marked them in a field 'deleted'. maybe your rendering does ignore this field? (which would be very unusual)
are the records still visible if you really delete the records in the database? then you propably have a strange cache which gets no clearing.

Answer (score 0):

This might caused by browser cache.

If you use extbase Repository to get the records, these deleted marked records will not be retrieved and also not shown in frontend.

Comment: Not really, this happens on external browers that were never connected to my typo3 too

Answer (score 0):

What kind/type of data record faces the problem? Is the record part of an extension? If yes, it might be that this extension ignores the delete/invisible flags of the DB table. As Bernd Wilke already recommended try to take a look in the DB directly and check if the concerned records has the datafield "deleted" set to "1".

Comment: They were set to 1, but still showing up. I deleted them permanently from the database - that fixed the problem :)

Comment: then your query probably missed the 'enablefields'. did you declare them properly in TCA? and did you use them? (no disabling)